# Parsing text, then searching it: one entry per position, vs. 1 JSON column per text

Tags: database, postgresql, search, database-design, nlp

### Situation

I have a Rails application using Postgresql.

Texts are added to the application (ranging in size from a few words to, say, 5,000 words).

The texts get parsed, first automatically, and then with some manual revision, to associate each word/position in the text with specific information (verb/noun/etc, base word (running ==> run), definition_id, grammar tags)

Given a lemma (base word, ex. "run"), or a part of speech (verb/noun), or grammar tags, or a definition_id (or a combination), I need to be able to find all the other text positions in the database that contain the same information.

### Conflict

I can't do a full-text search because, for example, if I click "left" on "I left Nashville", I don't want "turn left at the light" to appear. the traffic light. I just want "Leave" as a verb, as well as other forms of "Leave" as a verb.

Also, I might want just "left" with a specific definition_id (eg "Left" used as "The political party", not used as "the opposite of the right").

In short, I am looking for some advice on which of the following 3 routes I should take (or if there's a 4th or 5th route that I haven't considered).

### Solutions

There are three options I can think of:

**Option 1: TextPosition**

A TextPosition table to store each word position, with columns for each of the above attributes.

This would make searching very easy, but there would be MANY records (1 for each position), but maybe that's not a problem? Is storing this amount of tickets a bad idea for some specific reason?

**Option 2: JSON on the Text object**

A JSON column on the Text object, to store all word positions in a large array of hashes, or a hash of hashes.

This would add zero records, but, a) Building a query to search all texts with certain information would probably be difficult, b) That query would probably be slow, and c) It could take up more storage space than a separate table (TextPosition).

**Option 3: TWO JSON columns: one on the Text object, and one on each dictionary object**

1. A JSON in each text object, as in option 2, but only to render the text (not to search), containing all the information about each position in that same text.
2. Another JSON in each "dictionary object" (definition, base word, grammar concept, grammar tag), just for searching (not to render the text). This column would track the matches of this particular object across ALL texts. It would be an array of hashes, where each hash would be {text_id: x, text_index: y}.

With this option, the search would be "easier", but it would still not be ideal: to find all the text positions that contain a certain attribute, I would have to do the following:

1. Find the record for that attribute
2. Extract the text_ids / indexes from the record
3. Find the texts with those IDs
4. Extract the matching line from each text, using the index that comes with each text_id within the JSON.

If it was a combination of attributes that I were looking for, I would have to do those 4 steps for each attribute, and then find the intersection between the sets of matches for each attribute (to end up only having the positions that contain both).

Furthermore, when updating a position (for example, if a person indicates that an attribute is wrongly associated and that it should actually be another), I would have to update both JSONs.

Also, will storing 2 JSON columns actually bring any tangible benefit over a TextPosition table? It would probably take up MORE storage space than using a TextPosition table, and for what benefit?

### conclusion

In sum, I am looking for some advice on which of those 3 routes I should follow. I hope the answer is "option 1", but if so, I would love to know what drawbacks/obstacles could come up later when there are a ton of entries.

Thanks, Michael King

Answer (score 2):

Text parsing and searching make my brain hurt.  But anytime I have something with the complexity of what you are talking about, ElasticSearch is my tool of choice. You can do some amazingly complex indexing and searching with it.

So my answer is 4) ElasticSearch.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a steep learning curve? I.e. any rough time estimation on time it would take someone (me) who’s experienced with ruby/rails but no experience with elastic?

Comment: It’s pretty steep. I’d expect it to take at least a week to get a basic grounding, and another week to dig deep into the details for your particular application.